# How to check using Rest API Code, that the email has been delivered using flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate

''' An Email is being send using Power Automate, now to update the status of a column in SharePoint list, how to track the email has been delivered or not?
'''

---

Thanks Sir for your reply, The answer which is given is not correct. My question was different. Let me explain

If a flow sends an email to someone(Inside or Outside Microsoft Network), through which property Flow came to know that mail has been sent.

Here without knowing that the email has been send we just updating the status to yes.

And also Update File Properties is for documents/File not for an email.

Please check at your end and update..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a Yes/No field in SharePoint Library to determine if the message has been sent.

The default state of the field is No. Add Condition above Send an email action to determine if the value of this field is false. If so, the message can be sent.

After the message is sent, use Update file properties action to update the field value and change the state to Yes.

Similar thread is discussed here :

[How to check if mail was already sent?](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-to-check-if-mail-was-already-sent/td-p/258959)